# Can't ping parallels win xp vm from osx

Tags: macos, windows-xp, networking, ping, parallels

I'm not sure why, b/c I thought this was working b4, but when I have my Parallels Windows XP vm on [bridged network](http://kb.parallels.com/4948) I still can't ping the machine.. The Default Gateway is the same, and the osx and windowsXP ips both start with the same x.y.z, just the last digits are different which is what I wanted..

So any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows by default doesn't reply to pings. To make it reply, it is needed to either disable firewall in Windows, or allow pings-passing. Reffer to http://www.ucs.cam.ac.uk/docs/faq/windows/m8 for how this can be done